# Cropping videos in Windows Live Movie Maker

Tags: windows-7, video, editing, windows-movie-maker, crop

I want to crop (as in, take a subset of each frame, like when you crop a photo) a video in Windows Live Movie maker. Is there a way to do this, and failing that is there another free tool i can use to do that?

Comment: Anyone? Anyone at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used Windows Live Movie Maker for a while, and am 99.99% sure that it doesn't provide the ability to crop frames in a movie.

VirtualDub ([here](http://www.virtualdub.org/)) I've heard is a decent free video editor that can be used to crop videos (e.g. to remove those black bars and to rotate frames).

To crop a video in VirtualDub, open the video and then from the menu, select Video > Filters... > Add... > "null transform" > OK. Now select the "null transform" in the filter list and click "Cropping...". From this dialog you can drag the borders inwards to crop the video.

Comment: Windows Movie Maker unable to crop? that is pretty sad.. talk about a basic feature that was'nt implemented.

Comment: I thought .mp4 was a common extension, but VirtualDub does not open it :(

Answer (score 10):

I'd use Avidemux. Free, and portable version avaliable for Windows. [Download page](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html) , [Crop howto](http://avidemux.org/admWiki/index.php?title=Video_filter_Crop) . (Even supports multi-threading which was the original reason why I started to use it. Awesome software. :))

Comment: I'll check it out soon :)

Comment: After trying both this and VirtualDub, i prefer the other. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Avidemux supports .mp4 so definitely this one is better for me. It supports x265 HEVC too !